# Restrict product tags archive to certain users

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, terms

I want to restrict certain users to access to a 'product-tag' archive in the front-end.
I've tried to use several plugins but they only allow me to restrict access to pages or specific products.

Is there a way to achieve that?
Thanks,

Comment: how would the code know which users can see and which can't? Keep in mind recommendations are off topic here so any answer you get will require basic programming knowledge to use

Answer (score 0):

You could setup a redirect at the top of the archive page template for users that don't match your criteria, something like:

```
$user = wp_get_current_user();
$allowed = array( 'editor', 'administrator' );
$redirect_url = 'https://url-to-redirect-to';
if ( ! $user || ! array_intersect( $allowed, $user->roles ) ) {
   wp_safe_redirect( $redirect_url, 401 );
   exit;
}
```

The check for $allowed and $user role/meta depends on what you want to check for.